# Update связаных объектов одним запросом

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-model

Есть задача которая каждый день загружает посылки клиента (к примеру 3000 штук). Далее эти посылки создаются в базе. Нюанс в том что есть посылки в одинаковым `package_number` но с разным `vas_code`.
Пример таких посылок:

Посылка 1 (основная посылка):

- package_number = "370727320136718285"
- vas_code = "0000"

Посылка 2 (дочерняя посылка):

- package_number = "370727320136718285"
- vas_code = "3234" (марка)

Посылка 3 (дочерняя посылка):

- package_number = "370727320136718285"
- vas_code = "5800" (коробка)

После создания всех посылок их нужно связать между собой - для дочерних посылок установить основную посылку как `parent`.

Пример модели

```
class Package(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    package_number = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    vas_code = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```

Сейчас это происходит приблизительно так:

```
packages = []
for item in response:
    package = Package.objects.create(**item)
    if package.vas_code == "0000":
        packages.append(package)
```

и затем кусок который я хотел бы заменить одним запросом (без использования `for`)

```
for package in packages:
    Package.objects.filter(~Q(vas_code='0000'), package_number=package.package_number).update(parent=package)
```

Comment: а что значит заменить одним запросом? фактически он у вас один

Comment: @finally да, по повторяется на каждой итерации

Comment: ну у вас нарушена нормализация. и мне кажется сделать это после всех итераций не получится, вы же не зря делаете именно так. у вас ведь может  быть несколько посылок с 0000, соответственно для каждой такой вы должны искать ее дочерние посылки и проставлять им родителя

Comment: либо писать огромный неадекватный запрос с условиями, который все испортит

Comment: чисто в теории можете делать как: создаете вьюшку(в бд в смысле), туда кладете какой нибудь хэш от (номер посылки + вэс код) и соответственно айди родительской коробки. потом проходя по всем коробкам сразу можно будет брать их номер, подставлять туда 0000 и смотреть по хэшам какой айди будет родительским

Comment: либо можно в кэше это каком ни будь хранить, это не суть. главное тут придумать какео то правило, чтобы запрос в дальнейшем шел намного быстрее и проще

Comment: @finally тогда вопрос исчерпан :) благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @finally за то что натолкнул на мысль.

Решил задачу следующим путём

```
parent_packages = {}
child_packages = []
for item in response:
    package = Package.objects.create(**item)
    if package.vas_code == "0000":
        parent_packages[package.package_number] = package
    else:
        child_packages.append(package)
```

затем в функции которая должна связать посылки делаю

```
for child_package in child_packages:
    child_package.parent = parent_packages.get(
        child_package.package_number
    )

Package.objects.bulk_update(
    objs=child_packages,
    fields=['parent'],
    batch_size=1000
)
```

таким образом запрос в базу не происходит на каждой итерации

Comment: хорошее решение